# Is it possible to replace/overwrite a ui-router state definition? (default state being "customized" by another module)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to simply replace a state definition with a new one?

The use case I have is that one module defines the state, and I'd like to be able to replace that state definition from a different module. Basically the initial definition is a "default" definition, and I'd like to have the possibility to customize the state from a different module.

I realize that doing this at config time could result in a race condition on which module defines it first. I looked into the possibility of doing it at run-time, but couldn't get it working.

I can accomplish what I want by creating entirely new states, but I would like to use the same URL from the original state.

**Edit:**

To further clarify what I am trying to accomplish...
Please consider the following code:

```
angular.module('module1', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div class="layout sub" ui-view="sub"></div>'
        })
        .state('root.sub1', {
            url: '/sub1',
            views: {
                'sub@root': {
                    template: '<p>Default sub state 1</p>'
                }
            }
        });
}]);

angular.module('module2', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('root.sub1', {
            url: '/sub2',
            views: {
                'sub@root': {
                    template: '<p>Customized sub state 1</p>'
                }
            }
        });
}]);
```

Which of course gives "Error: State 'root.sub1'' is already defined"

Comment: You could probably get by using an abstract parent state. You can use the same URL in this situation. Can you expand on what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so as I was putting together a plnkr demo of what I tried next, I found that it actually works if you use $state.get and update it.

```
angular.module('module2', ['ui.router'])
.run(['$state', function($state){
  var state = $state.get('root.sub1');
  if(state && state.views && state.views['sub@root']){
    state.views['sub@root'].template = '<p>Customized sub state 1</p>';
  }
}]);
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xLdCgjeM33z2Hf5CHfZR

**Edit:**

I figured out that it wasn't working in my app because I didn't define the view I wanted to override in the original state.

**Example (doesn't work):**

```
angular.module('module1', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div class="layout sub" ui-view="sub"></div>'
        })
        .state('root.sub1', {
            url: '/sub1',
            views: {
            }
        });
}]);

angular.module('module2', ['ui.router'])
.run(['$state', function($state){
    var state = $state.get('root.sub1');
    if(state && state.views){
        state.views['sub@root'] = { template: '<p>Customized sub state 1</p>' };
    }
}]);
```

Comment: So now I wonder if there is a way to have that working so that adding a new view definition through $state.get will take effect...

Answer (score 2):

it seems like there is no way to overwrite it for < v1, unless you need to rewrite the decorator for the stateProvider.

for v1, there is a new method deregister for that purpose
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/44579ecbafe15ad587dc341ba4a80af78b62bdaa

I tried using $state.get(view) and overwrite the value, but the controller and template are not registered properly because the built-in decorator is using stateBuilder property to generate the controller and template.

check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.3.2/src/state.js

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I've found to solving this is to:

1. Create a 'root' controller (ie. a state that loads prior to other states)

> .state('root' , {   url: ':/root_path',   controller: 'rootController'   ..other stuff here })

2. In rootController, you decide what to do with the route:

> db.call(pull-root-key-from-db)   .then(function(root_response) {
>       if (root_response.type == "user") {
>         $state.go("user.dashboard") })

Sorry for formatting, I'm mobile :)